# Javascript: Nested JSON api request with multiple query parameters

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, api, express

I try to make an API for my next website and I have trouble to get multiple query results with the same url in an express app.

Dummy data:

```
var data = [{
    articles : [{
        id : '0',
        url : 'foo',
        title : 'Foo',
        body : 'some foo bar',
        category : 'foo',
        tags : [
            'foo'
        ]
    }, {
        id : '1',
        url : 'foo-bar',
        title : 'Foo bar',
        body : 'more foo bar',
        category : 'foo',
        tags : [
            'foo', 'bar'
        ]
    }, {
        id : '2',
        url : 'foo-bar-baz',
        title : 'Foo bar baz',
        body : 'more foo bar baz',
        category : 'foo',
        tags : [
            'foo',
            'bar',
            'baz'
        ]
    }]
}, {
    users : [{
        name: 'Admin'
    }, {
        name: 'User'
    }]
}];
```

Router:

```
// Grabs articles by categories and tags
// http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/articles/category/foo/tag/bar
router.get('/articles/category/:cat/tag/:tag', function(req, res) {
  var articles = data[0].articles;
  var q = articles.filter(function (article) {
    return article.category === req.params.cat;
    return article.tags.some(function(tagId) { return tagId === req.params.tag;});
  });
  res.json(q);
});
```

How I can nest the results if I requesting the `http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/articles/category/foo/tag/bar` url? Now if I do this, `tag` url is ignored, only `category` requests have effect.

Thank You for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rewrite your `return` statement as follows:

```
return article.category === req.params.cat &&
       article.tags.some(function(tagId) {
           return tagId === req.params.tag;
       });
```

... using the [`&&` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators), otherwise you will only test on the first condition, never reaching the other statement.

Here is a test when request is on category 'foo' and tag 'bar':

```js
var data =
[
  { articles:
    [
      { id: '0', url: 'audrey-hepburn', title: 'Audrey Hepburn', body: 'Nothing is impossible, the word itself says \'I\'m possible\'!', category: 'foo', tags: [ 'foo' ] },
      { id: '1', url: 'walt-disney', title: 'Walt Disney', body: 'You may not realize it when it happens, but a kick in the teeth may be the best thing in the world for you.', category: 'foo', tags: [ 'foo', 'bar' ] },
      { id: '2', url: 'unknown', title: 'Unknown', body: 'Even the greatest was once a beginner. Don\'t be afraid to take that first step.', category: 'bar', tags: [ 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' ] },
      { id: '3', url: 'neale-donald-walsch', title: 'Neale Donald Walsch', body: 'You are afraid to die, and you\'re afraid to live. What a way to exist.', category: 'bar', tags: [ 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' ] }
    ]
  },
  { users:
    [
      { name: 'Admin' },
      { name: 'User' }
    ]
  }
];

req = {params: {cat: 'foo', tag: 'bar'}};

var articles = data[0].articles;
var q = articles.filter(function (article) {
    return article.category === req.params.cat &&
           article.tags.some(function(tagId) { 
               return tagId === req.params.tag;
           });
});

document.write('<pre>', JSON.stringify(q, null, 4), '</pre>');
```

See how it matches the last entry.

Comment: Using this also just only the `category` request works and tags are ignored. I requesting with `res.json(q);`.

Comment: It's strange. When I'm use your exact same code in my app, the API request's tag parameter is not working. Here is my repo's URL: https://github.com/DJviolin/horgalleryNode/blob/master/routes/api.js

Comment: I putted the updated URL in my code, but for some reason I've got an error on server start: `SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^\/articles\/(?(?:([^\/]+?))\/(?:([^\/]+?))|tag\/(?:([^\/]+?)))\/?$/: Invalid group`.

Comment: I think I might have misunderstood. You want to do requests like this: `/articles/category/foo/tag/bar`. Is that right? Could you put back the original `router.get(/articles/category/:cat/tag/:tag', ...` URL pattern and in the function just output `res.json(req.params);`. I want to make sure you see bot the category and tag in that `params`.

Comment: Correct. I want to get the category first and also get the results from this category's matching tags.
I done the url pattern revert to original & the res.json change. This is what it's outputting for the following url http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/articles/category/foo/tag/baz: `{ cat : "foo",tag : "baz" }`.

Comment: OK, that means the URL pattern is working correctly. Forget everything I wrote about that, I reverted my answer back to what it was before. Let me check now what else could be going wrong...

Comment: So do you want the result to have both the category `foo` AND at the same time have a tag `baz`? Or is one of them matching enough?

Comment: I want both match at the same time. So first matching the category and also matching this category's tags. For a single match only enough the `/articles/category/:id` and the `/articles/tag/:id` from the other routes in this file: https://github.com/DJviolin/horgalleryNode/blob/master/routes/api.js Later on I want use this method to separate posts into pages too (somehow, this is for future problem...).

Comment: I updated my answer, using the data you have on github, and replaced the `||` operator with `&&` which makes it  required that both the cat and tag conditions are met.

Comment: I beautified a little bit the api router. Thank You again your help! :)
https://github.com/DJviolin/horgalleryNode/blob/master/routes/api.js

Comment: It is doing the category test repeatedly now (which is not needed), but I can see you like this better. You could also consider replacing `article.tags.some(...)` by `article.tags.indexOf(req.params.tag) != -1`

Comment: I changed the code this as suggested in the categories and tags router: `article.tags.indexOf(req.params.tag) !== -1;`, but in the tag router I can't change to this because it fails. Do you mean `It is doing the category test repeatedly now` that I requesting the categories and the categories & tags in a separate router and this can cause performance issues in my script or other problem?

Comment: No, I meant that as you moved the `article.category === req.params.cat` inside the `some` callback function, you actually multiply the execution of that test, which will always be the same. But really, this should not have much of a performance impact. It's OK.

Comment: I also implemented some kind of request authentication `var apiToken = 'password';` and at every route: `apiToken === req.params.token`. Plus this route end: `/:token`. https://github.com/DJviolin/horgalleryNode/blob/master/routes/api.js Probably this is dirt stupid solution, but for my static site probably it will be enough to only my site can access the API.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is here >>

```
return article.category === req.params.cat;
return article.tags.some(function(tagId) { return tagId === req.params.tag;});
```

first `return` statement will stop further action within function
so you need `if ... else` or `case` or helper function here

Comment: `return article.category === req.params.cat, article.tags.some(function(tagId) { return tagId === req.params.tag;});` seems like work. Is it a good solution? EDIT: Nope. Returning every category. Tags working instead.

Comment: No, `return` in this case will execute all but return last statement

Comment: You can try `[articles].indexOf(el)` and `[tags].indexOf(el)` if the both are Arrays.